# how to avoid the top: -30px in bootstrap?

Tags: bootstrap-4

I use a spinner

```
<div class="module-loader2" style="position: relative; top: -30px; margin: 0 auto;" >
   <div class="loader-bubble loader-bubble-primary d-block"></div>
</div>
```

I would like to avoid the following properties:

```
style="position: relative; top: -30px; margin: 0 auto;" >
```

What is the property in bootsrap to replace `top:-30` and `margin: 0 auto`, please?

Comment: I have provided you an answer I hope it may help you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you mentioned you are using bootstrap 4. Bootstrap also provides some classes for position and margin. You may have a look here:

> https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/utilities/position/

For margin auto you can use the `mx-auto` class of bootstrap.

**For Example**

```
<div class="mx-auto" style="width: 200px;">
  Centered element
</div>
```

And for positioning some examples are here:

```
<div class="position-static">...</div>
<div class="position-relative">...</div>
<div class="position-absolute">...</div>
<div class="position-fixed">...</div>
<div class="position-sticky">...</div>
<div class="fixed-top">...</div>
<div class="fixed-bottom">...</div>
<div class="sticky-top">...</div>
```